# Backbone : How to display JSON data with timestamp as key

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following data JSON (model), with timestamp as key:

```
var data = {
         "comments": {
               "1372164369": {
                     "author": "user 1",
                     "comments": "Comment 1",
                },
                "1372164370": {
                     "author": "user 2 ",
                     "comments": "Comment 2",
    }}}
```

Need help please. I haven’t any idea to display this data in my template? How can I do?

Comment: try `jsonVar["comments"][0]["1372164369"].author`

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript Object, [JSON is a string in a particular format](http://json.org).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your syntax is not correct. It should be

```
var data = {
    "comments": {
          "1372164369": {
          "author": "user 1",
            "comments": "Comment 1",
    },
        "1372164370": {
        "author": "user 2 ",
            "comments": "Comment 2",
        }}
}
```

Then use a loop in underscore template

```
<script type="text/template" id="list_template">
    <ul> 
        <% _.each(comments, function(item, key) { %> 
            <li class = "btn" > <%= key + ":" + item.author + ":" + item.comments %> </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Pass the data in `template` function

```
_.template($("#list_template").html(), {comments:data.comments});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rNgHb/